# Too many redirects error using Python requests

Tags: python, redirect, dns, python-requests, http-request

HTTP requests are working fine on my localhost, but running the same HTTP requests using the python requests library on my server returns a "Too Many Redirects" error

When I enter

```
localhost/terminal/jfk
```

in a browser, I get a json dictionary as expected.

However, when I run the following in python using the python requests library on my server

```
requests.get('http://splitmyri.de/terminal/jfk')
```

I receive a "Too Many Redirects" error from the requests module.

Any thoughts as to what's causing the error? Or recommendations for narrowing potential causes?

Comment: could you please tell us what json you think you're supposed to get from a GoDaddy.com empty domain name page?

Comment: It should return a json of airlines and their arrivals terminals (along with some other data).

Comment: I understand what happened now... See my response below... Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Asha,

After you responded that this really is your site, I checked out why I was getting an empty GoDaddy.com page. The problem is that your DNS entry for splitmyri.de is returning two different A records...

**Analyzing results, using 107.10.141.119**:
Hard coding `107.10.141.119        splitmyri.de` in my `/etc/hosts` file allowed me to make queries to 107.10.141.119, which returns "this is my site" in `index.html` (then I checked http://splitmyri.de/terminal/ and got an empty json hash, with a mime type=[application/json]). Checking the reverse entry for this address returns an Amazon AWS host (the kind of entry I expect for a real web page).  Now your code above works as expected...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14) 
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://splitmyri.de/terminal/')
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://splitmyri.de/terminal/').content
u'{}'
>>> # requests.get('http://splitmyri.de/terminal/jfk').content returns a huge json hash
```

**Analyzing results using 68.178.232.100**:
Performing the same drill with queries to 68.178.232.100 gets an empty GoDaddy.com page.  Reverse mapping this address turns up a typical entry for a parked domain.  Sending a request here returns `TooManyRedirects` as you saw in your attempts...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14) 
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> foo = requests.get('http://splitmyri.de/terminal/jfk')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests/api.py", line 50, in get
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests/api.py", line 37, in request
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests/sessions.py", line 170, in request
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests/models.py", line 383, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/requests/models.py", line 210, in _build_response
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects
>>>
```

**SOLUTION**: 
Fix your DNS for splitmyri.de (removing the A record for 68.178.232.100) and all will be good.

Including the DNS info below as an FYI...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig splitmyri.de

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> splitmyri.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54051
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;splitmyri.de.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
splitmyri.de.           3193    IN      A       68.178.232.100
splitmyri.de.           3193    IN      A       107.20.141.119

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
splitmyri.de.           3193    IN      NS      ns49.domaincontrol.com.
splitmyri.de.           3193    IN      NS      ns50.domaincontrol.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns49.domaincontrol.com. 3193    IN      A       216.69.185.25
ns49.domaincontrol.com. 3193    IN      AAAA    2607:f208:206::19
ns50.domaincontrol.com. 3193    IN      A       208.109.255.25
ns50.domaincontrol.com. 3193    IN      AAAA    2607:f208:302::19

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 26 05:14:51 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 205

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ 
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig -x 107.20.141.119

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> -x 107.20.141.119
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41049
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 6

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;119.141.20.107.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
119.141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 300 IN     PTR     ec2-107-20-141-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns1.ultradns.net.
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns2.ultradns.net.
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns3.ultradns.org.
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns5.ultradns.info.
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns4.ultradns.org.
141.20.107.in-addr.arpa. 900    IN      NS      pdns6.ultradns.co.uk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
pdns1.ultradns.net.     86400   IN      A       204.74.108.1
pdns1.ultradns.net.     86400   IN      AAAA    2001:502:f3ff::1
pdns2.ultradns.net.     86400   IN      A       204.74.109.1
pdns3.ultradns.org.     86400   IN      A       199.7.68.1
pdns4.ultradns.org.     86400   IN      A       199.7.69.1
pdns4.ultradns.org.     86400   IN      AAAA    2001:502:4612::1

;; Query time: 306 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 26 05:09:47 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 392

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig -x 68.178.232.100

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> -x 68.178.232.100
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38578
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;100.232.178.68.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
100.232.178.68.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR     parkwebwin-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
232.178.68.in-addr.arpa. 3600   IN      NS      cns1.secureserver.net.
232.178.68.in-addr.arpa. 3600   IN      NS      cns2.secureserver.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
cns1.secureserver.net.  3600    IN      A       208.109.255.100
cns2.secureserver.net.  3600    IN      A       216.69.185.100

;; Query time: 173 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 26 05:12:06 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 171

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I was actually able to remove the 'TooManyRedirects' error after I fixed some (seemingly) unrelated regex bugs in my python code, meaning it seemed to work without removing the A record 68.178.232.100. However, definitely needed to clean that up... (that was the IP for an old AWS EC2 instance). Thanks for your detective work!

Comment: The problem was the A record; DNS round-robins responses, and there is a one-hour timeout. You didn't see the problem again because you got a different response to a DNS query for splitmyri.de.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to narrow down the problem, a good idea is to use `wireshark` and analyse the different connections and their content. Like this you will see what is transferred over the wire. Good for debugging TCP related problems. Additionally, you may use the `pdb` Python module and debug your program. Issue `pdb.set_trace()` right before the call, then single step into the function and see what it does. More info about `pdb` can be found in the Python documentation or by pressing `?`.

Comment: I have my doubts that this is a real question, I think it is content spam

Comment: Very useful! thanks @hochl. Don't have enough reputation points to vote you up directly :( pdb is really useful though, thanks!