# Python Requests <TooManyRedirects> for freshdirect.com

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests, runtime-error

I hope you are staying safe. Because delivery slots for groceries are so hard to come by due to COVID-19, I created a web scraper to notify me of delivery slots on freshdirect.com. When I use `requests.get("https://freshdirect.com")`, I get a TooManyRedirects error. I have found a number of online answers related to user agents, but it doesn't work with a Postman or Firefox on Windows. I works fine when I change the headers on Chrome using the [requestly](https://requestly.in). I found another answer relating to DNS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896842/too-many-redirects-error-using-python-requests), but I haven't been able to figure out how that can fix my problem. I have also removed the max redirect limitation, but then the request just hangs, and eventually times out. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** My code is [here](https://ghostbin.co/paste/s3nd5)

Comment: Does `print( requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}).text )` work?

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for your response. It works in an interpreter, but when I added it to my code, the code gets stuck. I have added a link to the code, would you mind checking it out? The pertinent parts should be the function on line 73 and the class on line 59 (I think).